# Angular http post converting non-latin chars to?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular factory which posts request to a servlet (TOMCAT) which, in its turn, accesses DB to send/retrieve data:

```
MyApp.factory('DB_Services', function($http , $q) {
var l_Result ;
var DB_Services = function(p_Query) {
                        var l_deferred = $q.defer();
                        var l_url      = "http://localhost:8080/Services/Dispatcher?";
                        var l_params   = 'request=' + JSON.stringify(p_Query) ;

                        console.log("DB_Services - l_params is: " + l_params ) ;

                        var req = { url: l_url, method:"POST", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                                                        }, data: l_params
                                  } ;
                        console.log("DB_Services - req is: " + JSON.stringify(req)   ) ;

                        $http(req ).
                                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                        console.log("DB_Services - Success; data is: " + JSON.stringify(data)) ;
                                         l_deferred.resolve(data);
                                    }).
                                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                        console.log("DB_Services - Error: " + data) ;
                                         l_deferred.reject(status);
                                    });
                                     return l_deferred.promise;

                    } ;

return DB_Services;
});
```

The function works "ALMOST" perfectly, being the only issue (at least for now) that non-Latin chars are returned as "?". I checked the TOMCAT logs where I print what is being retrieved from the DB and sent back to the client, and all non-Latin chars are shown OK.

I guess I'm missing telling Angular/HTTP that the response is a JSON with UTF-8 chars encoding. If my guess is correct, how do I add this information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have this line in the head tag of your page: `<meta charset="utf-8">` ?

Comment: Yes, I have. Perhaps this will focus more my question. Initially, before starting the integration with the DB, I had a manually populated JSON with all languages and it was shown OK. It would look that the issue is with the HTTP-POST handling of chat sets.

Comment: XmlHttpRequest uses `utf-8` by default. Sounds like a server side or database issue

Comment: The servlet logs the received request and the sent response into a log file. There, all non-Latin strings are shown OK. The DB had been created with UTF-8 encoding (which is also the default I think). I know (saw somewhere) that there is room to specify UTF-8 in the request. I just don't know where and how.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and I solved it by executing the following SQL: `SET NAMES utf8` (This is how I do it using PDO: `new PDO( "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}", $username, $password, array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8" ) )`)

Comment: It is a MySQL DB, and use the following string: `jdbc:mysql://MySqlServer.com:3306/DB-1?user=user&password=password&noAccessToProcedureBodies=true`.

Comment: The question @AlonEitan is then: Why do I see the correct data in the TOMCAT if my access to the DB is the issue?

Comment: Hummm.... I wish I'd knew why :( But your description is similar to the issue I had. Last attempt: Try to append `;charset=utf8` to your connection string. If this doesn't help then i'm sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: @AlonEitan, Nope. After adding what you suggested I get an error and no data can be retrieved. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found the issue and solved. The only thing I needed to do is to add the following line within the Servlet's DoPost function:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Once this was done, I now receive all strings with the correct characters (Cyrillic, Chinese, Arab, etc.).

Thanks to [this guy](http://www.aviransplace.com/2010/03/09/utf-8-encoding-in-post-and-get-request-on-tomcat/) for posting his solution!!!